# Ошибка при apt-get update к своему репозиторию Debian: The following signatures were invalid

Tags: linux, debian, repository, apt-get, gpg

1. На сервере с Centos7 поднял Debian репозиторий: /var/www/repo/debian/.
2. Создал gpg-ключ и подписал им файл /var/www/repo/debian/dists/main/Release командой: sudo gpg -abs -o Release.gpg Release. В данной директории появился файл Release.gpg
3. Сделал экспорт публичного gpg-ключа командой sudo gpg -a --export > deb-gpg-key
4. На клиентской машине c Debian в файл /etc/apt/sources.list добавил ссылку на репозиторий: deb http://myrepoulr/debian main soft
5. При помощи команды sudo apt-key add deb-gpg-key добавил публичный ключ
6. Делаю sudo apt-get update и получаю ошибку: W: GPG error: http://myrepourl/debian main Release: The following signatures were invalid: BADE..........................AA6
   E: The repository 'http://myrepourl/debian main Release' is not signed.
   N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.

Что делаю не так?
Как-то можно проверить, что репозиторий подписан правильно?

Comment: Попробуйте sudo apt-get update -f -y имя

Comment: @kiten "имя" чего, простите?

Comment: Опечатка. Имя файла, если это установка

Comment: @kitenОшибка: E: Command line option 'f' [from -f] is not understood in combination with the other options.

Comment: Я ubuntu пользуюсь, может в debian по-другому

Comment: @kiten Debian: ~$ apt-get update help
E: The update command takes no arguments

Comment: сверьте сигнатуры. 1. посмотрите сигнатуру ключа, которым подписан файл: `$ gpg --verify Release.gpg Release`. 2. посмотрите, есть ли этот ключ среди известных apt-у: `$ apt-key list`

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin Перегенерировал ключи с пунктом (2) DSA and Elgamal и всё заработало. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Решение проблемы:
При генерации gpg-ключа: gpg --gen-key изначально выбирал пункт (1) RSA and RSA (default).
Удалил все ключи и сгенерировал новые с пунктом (2) DSA and Elgamal.
Переподписал репозиторий и перезаписал публичный ключ на клиентской машине.

После этого всё заработало.